# Laravel \URL::to('/') could not auto detect HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel

I need to auto generate base URL. (client may use HTTP or HTTPS)

I use `\URL::to('/')` but, it output HTTP even current site is in HTTPS

Anyone know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use `URL::forceScheme()` in your `AppServiceProvider's` `boot` method;

Comment: If you are using older laravel version then use `URL::forceSchema()`

Comment: or at last `url()` have the third parameter for https. You can use it by using `url('/',null,true)`. This will also give the https URL.

Comment: what I need is auto detect, cuz some of client dont use https

Comment: write a middleware to redirect all `http` to `https`.

Comment: You can check for request headers and based on that if using the https use `URL::forceScheme()`

Comment: The request protocol might be getting forwarded. Does your server sit behind a load balancer?